# Executing a variable in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

The below procedure compiled successfully. But, when I try to run the its getting error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE 
AS
VARIABLE1 VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
VARIABLE1:='DECLARE A TIMESTAMP:=LOCALTIMESTAMP; 
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_BWXROW
   (ROW_ID NUMBER(10),DIVISION VARCHAR2(256),OUTLET VARCHAR2(256),CLASS VARCHAR2(256));';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VARIABLE1;
END;
```

Error is:

```
6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Can you help me, what is wrong in this.

Comment: Why `declare`-ing something in this dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Very strange to be dynamically creating a global temporary table. Anyway, I assume this is all part of a learning exercise ...

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE 
AS
  VARIABLE1 VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  VARIABLE1:='DECLARE A TIMESTAMP:=LOCALTIMESTAMP; 
              BEGIN
              CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_BWXROW
                (ROW_ID NUMBER(10),
                 DIVISION VARCHAR2(256),
                 OUTLET VARCHAR2(256),
                 CLASS VARCHAR2(256));
              END';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VARIABLE1;
END;
```

Comment: If the goal is to use dynamic PL/SQL, the `CREATE TABLE` statement inside the dynamic PL/SQL block would have to itself use dynamic SQL.  A riddle wrapped in a mystery surrounded by an enigma why someone would want such a beast...

Comment: The requirement is like that, dynamically the query will append to the variable until ending of the procedure. After that need to execute the variable. The logic migrated from SQL server, where I created a temporary tables dynamically and at the end need to be executed.

Comment: @user1990383 - You understand that temporary tables in Oracle are radically different, right?  A temporary table in Oracle is visible to all sessions.  A temporary table in Oracle is only created once.  It does not have session-level scope or get removed automatically in Oracle like it does in SQL Server.  Naively porting code from SQL Server to Oracle is going to lead to a world of pain.

Comment: Where is final `;` after `end`?

Comment: Ok, I am new to the oracle database. Can you suggest me what should be there in the place of temporary tables in oracle, where I am using Temporary tables in sql server.

Comment: What is the business goal you're trying to accomplish with temporary tables?  Maybe you need something like PL/SQL arrays in memory, not a temporary table.

Comment: Have a look at common table expressions -- WITH TEMP_BWXROW as ( SELECT ... ) etc.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this is that you almost certainly shouldn't be creating a table at runtime and you almost certainly shouldn't be using dynamic PL/SQL and you really, really, really shouldn't be creating a table dynamically inside a dynamic PL/SQL block.

If you are absolutely determined to do so, the `CREATE TABLE` statement would itself need to use dynamic SQL inside of the dynamic PL/SQL block.  If I've got all my quotes escaped correctly, you'd end up with something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROCEDURE 
AS
  VARIABLE1 VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  VARIABLE1:='DECLARE 
                A TIMESTAMP:=LOCALTIMESTAMP; 
              BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_BWXROW
                                    (ROW_ID NUMBER(10),
                                     DIVISION VARCHAR2(256),
                                     OUTLET VARCHAR2(256),
                                     CLASS VARCHAR2(256))'';
              END;';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VARIABLE1;
END;
```

If I came across a piece of code doing this in one of my systems, though, I would have a very strongly worded conversation with the original developer to understand what possessed them to believe that any problem necessitated PL/SQL executing a dynamic PL/SQL block that itself executed a dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: Where is final `;` after `end`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - Yup, I missed that.

Comment: "Create GTT" dynamic SQL must not have final `;`.

Comment: @Justin Cave - Ok, I am new to the oracle database. Can you suggest me what should be there in the place of temporary tables in oracle, where I am using Temporary tables in sql server.

Comment: The requirement is like this, dynamically the query will append to the variable until ending of the procedure. After that need to execute the variable. The logic migrated from SQL server, where I created a temporary tables dynamically and at the end need to be executed.

Comment: @user1990383 - It depends on why you are using temporary tables in SQL Server.  There is a thread over on the DBA stack that discusses various reasons that one might use a temporary table in other databases and other approaches in Oracle http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34279/temporary-table-inside-procedure-oracle/34322#34322

Comment: @Justin Cave - Ok, Shall I send you the entire procedure that was migrated from sql server. For some extent I changed the code. Remaining Can you help ?

Comment: @user1990383 - If you want to post that as a new question (and you can make the question sufficiently focused to be answerable), sure.  Make sure that you explain the business problem not just the technical implementation.

Comment: @Justin Cave - I try to explain the requirement as shortly. In my requirement, from table I'll be getting column names differs each time. Based upon the columns i need to create the table, then I need to insert the rows into this created table and start the process by using this table.. All this process is stored in variable, finally this variable will be executed.

Comment: @user1990383 - First, that sounds like something that should go in the new question that you want to open.  Second, that's still not explaining the business problem.  Why do you need to fetch column names dynamically?  What do you know about the columns that you are fetching?  Why do you need to use a temporary table?

Comment: @Justin Cave - The user will insert a row into the table having comma separated column names, which i need to take when each user calls the procedure.

Comment: @user1990383 - Again, this appears to be something that should go in the new question that you want to open.  And we're still not discussing the business problem.  We're still discussing the technical implementation.  Presumably, the business user doesn't say "I want to write an INSERT statement that inserts a comma-separated list of column names into a table".  The business user has some business problem and this is part of the technical solution you chose in SQL Server.  You may need a completely different technical solution to whatever business problem you have.